# Would it be bad practice to use encase javascript in inline elements for styling purposes?

Tags: javascript, css

Would it be bad practice to use encase printed text from javascript in inline elements for styling purposes?  If so, what's the appropriate way to style javascript printed text?

Ex:

```
<script>
function produceMessage(){
    var msg= 'This should print';
    return msg;
}
</script>


<span style="color:red">script>
document.write(produceMessage());
</script></span>
```

EDIT: `Changed document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(produceMessage()));` to     d`ocument.write(produceMessage());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would it be bad practice to use encase printed text from javascript in inline elements for styling purposes?

Generally speaking, yes. Build JavaScript over HTML. If part of the document doesn't make sense without the JavaScript running, then it should be added with JavaScript and not be in the basic HTML.

> If so, what's the appropriate way to style javascript printed text?

Generate appropriate, semantic markup along with the text.  (Span is a last resort for when nothing in HTML describes the semantics of what you are adding).

> `<span style="color:red"><script>document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(produceMessage()));`

That wouldn't work anyway. The text is being appended to the `<body>` element so will not be inside the `<span>`.

Answer (score 0):

Give the `<span>` element an ID and insert the text using `innerHTML`:

```
document.getElementById("element_id").innerHTML = "string";

<span id="element_id"></span>
```